# PostgreSQL JDBC URL with database name containing forward slash

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a database named **sales/pre** in postgreSQL. While connecting to this database with JDBC application, the characters after forward slash get omitted, and I get the following error:

> FATAL: database "sales" does not exist.

Is there a way to escape the forward slash?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a JDBC URL so you need to url encode your forward slash e.g.

`jdbc:postgresql://host:port/sales%2Fpre`

Alternatively choose a different database name.

Comment: Not all JDBC drivers use URL encoding (and the JDBC standard doesn't actually say anything about it), so it might work for PostgreSQL (I don't know), but that doesn't mean it works for all JDBC drivers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel is correct, I t doesn't encode forward slash, I get same error saying  `FATAL: database sales%2Fpre does not exist`